# How to extract different types of JSON object while publishing them in a Listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement something like a newsfeed in my flutter app. Below is the Json I recieve from the backend

```
[
     {
        "date": "2020-03-25T12:29:12.913Z",
        "comments": [
            "5e7b52ce5c28ee49f8e601a6",
            "5e7b530fdcfdf940cc4862c3",
            "5e7b553e0d2a54433cbbf46b"
        ],
        "UpVote": [
            "5e79a7efc8a01207cc3f8b1d"
        ],
        "DownVote": [],
        "_id": "5e7b4e98ccc6d52a4467d096",
        "Author": "5e79a7efc8a01207cc3f8b1d",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e7e448bc27b4206280754d5",
        "NewsSource": "The Washington Post",
        "Reporter": "Carolyn Y. Johnson, Ben Guarino",
        "Title": "Blood from people who recover from coronavirus could provide a treatment - The Washington Post",
        "Description": "People who recover from the coronavirus could play an essential role in fighting the disease -- by donating plasma that could help others fight off infection.",
        "Content": "The possible therapy is based on a medical concept called passive immunity. People who recover from an infection develop antibodies that circulate in the blood and can neutralize the pathogen. Infusions of plasma the whitish liquid that remains when blood cel… [+6661 chars]",
        "Url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/health/2020/03/27/coronavirus-serum-plasma-treatment/",
        "PublishedAt": "2020-03-27T18:23:07.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

As you can see above, it has two types of format. One is showing a normal post with upvote and downvote and the another is showing a news. I had been trying to create a future to fetch it like:

```
Future<List<FeedPost>> getPosts () async{
    var res= await http.get('$SERVER_IP/Posts/0', headers: {"authorization" : "Token $jwtt"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var postInput = res.body;
      var jwtJson =  json.decode(postInput.toString());
      var jwtString = FeedPost.fromJson(jwtJson);
      var postMap = {
        'date': jwtString.date,
        'author': jwtString.author
      };
      var author = jwtString.author;
      return jwtString;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error collecting the data');
    }
  }
```

The above code is wrong in the sense that it should `return` things in type `List<FeedPost>`

FeedPost is the class I made to convert the first types of post.

Comment: If your method is `async` then it can only return a `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : Because `cel…` in your json string and `…` is special character, so there is extra encode and decode 
Step 2 : You can check `snapshot.data[index].author` to classify data and decide to return data you need or `return Container()` for not show this data

code snippet

```
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\n", "");
var res = http.Response(String.fromCharCodes(utf8.encode(jsonString)), 200);
if (res.statusCode == 200) {     
  List<FeedPost> feedPostList =
      feedPostFromJson(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));
  return feedPostList;

...
    return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (snapshot.data[index].author != null) {
        return Text(snapshot.data[index].author);
      } else {
        return Card(
            elevation: 6.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 6.0,
                  bottom: 6.0,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

List<FeedPost> feedPostFromJson(String str) =>
    List<FeedPost>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => FeedPost.fromJson(x)));

String feedPostToJson(List<FeedPost> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class FeedPost {
  String date;
  List<String> comments;
  List<String> upVote;
  List<dynamic> downVote;
  String id;
  String author;
  int v;
  String newsSource;
  String reporter;
  String title;
  String description;
  String content;
  String url;
  String publishedAt;

  FeedPost({
    this.date,
    this.comments,
    this.upVote,
    this.downVote,
    this.id,
    this.author,
    this.v,
    this.newsSource,
    this.reporter,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.content,
    this.url,
    this.publishedAt,
  });

  factory FeedPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FeedPost(
        date: json["date"] == null ? null : json["date"],
        comments: json["comments"] == null
            ? null
            : List<String>.from(json["comments"].map((x) => x)),
        upVote: json["UpVote"] == null
            ? null
            : List<String>.from(json["UpVote"].map((x) => x)),
        downVote: json["DownVote"] == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(json["DownVote"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["_id"] == null ? null : json["_id"],
        author: json["Author"] == null ? null : json["Author"],
        v: json["__v"] == null ? null : json["__v"],
        newsSource: json["NewsSource"] == null ? null : json["NewsSource"],
        reporter: json["Reporter"] == null ? null : json["Reporter"],
        title: json["Title"] == null ? null : json["Title"],
        description: json["Description"] == null ? null : json["Description"],
        content: json["Content"] == null ? null : json["Content"],
        url: json["Url"] == null ? null : json["Url"],
        publishedAt: json["PublishedAt"] == null ? null : json["PublishedAt"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date": date == null ? null : date,
        "comments": comments == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(comments.map((x) => x)),
        "UpVote":
            upVote == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(upVote.map((x) => x)),
        "DownVote": downVote == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(downVote.map((x) => x)),
        "_id": id == null ? null : id,
        "Author": author == null ? null : author,
        "__v": v == null ? null : v,
        "NewsSource": newsSource == null ? null : newsSource,
        "Reporter": reporter == null ? null : reporter,
        "Title": title == null ? null : title,
        "Description": description == null ? null : description,
        "Content": content == null ? null : content,
        "Url": url == null ? null : url,
        "PublishedAt": publishedAt == null ? null : publishedAt,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Future<List<FeedPost>> _future;

  Future<List<FeedPost>> getPosts() async {
    //var res= await http.get('$SERVER_IP/Posts/0', headers: {"authorization" : "Token $jwtt"});
    String jsonString = r'''
    [
     {
        "date": "2020-03-25T12:29:12.913Z",
        "comments": [
            "5e7b52ce5c28ee49f8e601a6",
            "5e7b530fdcfdf940cc4862c3",
            "5e7b553e0d2a54433cbbf46b"
        ],
        "UpVote": [
            "5e79a7efc8a01207cc3f8b1d"
        ],
        "DownVote": [],
        "_id": "5e7b4e98ccc6d52a4467d096",
        "Author": "5e79a7efc8a01207cc3f8b1d",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e7e448bc27b4206280754d5",
        "NewsSource": "The Washington Post",
        "Reporter": "Carolyn Y. Johnson, Ben Guarino",
        "Title": "Blood from people who recover from coronavirus could provide a treatment - The Washington Post",
        "Description": "People who recover from the coronavirus could play an essential role in fighting the disease -- by donating plasma that could help others fight off infection.",
        "Content": "The possible therapy is based on a medical concept called passive immunity. People who recover from an infection develop antibodies that circulate in the blood and can neutralize the pathogen. Infusions of plasma the whitish liquid that remains when blood cel… [+6661 chars]",
        "Url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/health/2020/03/27/coronavirus-serum-plasma-treatment/",
        "PublishedAt": "2020-03-27T18:23:07.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
    ''';
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\n", "");
    var res = http.Response(String.fromCharCodes(utf8.encode(jsonString)), 200);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      /*var postInput = res.body;
      var jwtJson =  json.decode(postInput.toString());
      var jwtString = FeedPost.fromJson(jwtJson);
      var postMap = {
        'date': jwtString.date,
        'author': jwtString.author
      };
      var author = jwtString.author;
      return jwtString;*/
      List<FeedPost> feedPostList =
          feedPostFromJson(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));
      return feedPostList;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error collecting the data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getPosts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<FeedPost>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (snapshot.data[index].author != null) {
                            return Text(snapshot.data[index].author);
                          } else {
                            return Card(
                                elevation: 6.0,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 6.0,
                                      bottom: 6.0,
                                      left: 8.0,
                                      right: 8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data[index].newsSource,
                                      ),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data[index].reporter,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ));
                          }
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quicktype.io](https://Quicktype.io)

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<FeedData> feedDataFromJson(String str) => List<FeedData>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => FeedData.fromJson(x)));

String feedDataToJson(List<FeedData> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class FeedData {
    DateTime date;
    List<String> comments;
    List<String> upVote;
    List<dynamic> downVote;
    String id;
    String author;
    int v;
    String newsSource;
    String reporter;
    String title;
    String description;
    String content;
    String url;
    DateTime publishedAt;

    FeedData({
        this.date,
        this.comments,
        this.upVote,
        this.downVote,
        this.id,
        this.author,
        this.v,
        this.newsSource,
        this.reporter,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.content,
        this.url,
        this.publishedAt,
    });

    factory FeedData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FeedData(
        date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        comments: json["comments"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["comments"].map((x) => x)),
        upVote: json["UpVote"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["UpVote"].map((x) => x)),
        downVote: json["DownVote"] == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json["DownVote"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["_id"],
        author: json["Author"] == null ? null : json["Author"],
        v: json["__v"],
        newsSource: json["NewsSource"] == null ? null : json["NewsSource"],
        reporter: json["Reporter"] == null ? null : json["Reporter"],
        title: json["Title"] == null ? null : json["Title"],
        description: json["Description"] == null ? null : json["Description"],
        content: json["Content"] == null ? null : json["Content"],
        url: json["Url"] == null ? null : json["Url"],
        publishedAt: json["PublishedAt"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["PublishedAt"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date": date == null ? null : date.toIso8601String(),
        "comments": comments == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(comments.map((x) => x)),
        "UpVote": upVote == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(upVote.map((x) => x)),
        "DownVote": downVote == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(downVote.map((x) => x)),
        "_id": id,
        "Author": author == null ? null : author,
        "__v": v,
        "NewsSource": newsSource == null ? null : newsSource,
        "Reporter": reporter == null ? null : reporter,
        "Title": title == null ? null : title,
        "Description": description == null ? null : description,
        "Content": content == null ? null : content,
        "Url": url == null ? null : url,
        "PublishedAt": publishedAt == null ? null : publishedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

Then you can check if `newsSource` is null then it is type - 1 else type to..Then you can write your design logic according to the type inside a `loop` or `Builder()`